# Installing Asterisk 13 + FreePBX 12.0.7

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, asterisk, freepbx

I am trying to install Asterisk 13 with FreePBX 12.0.7 on a clear Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS Server. But i have trouble with installing FreePBX.
I tried to reinstall it on clear Ubuntu about 5 times, but I have the same problem.

When running command in bash:

```
./install_amp --installdb --username=asteriskuser --password=${ASTERISK_DB_PW}
```

After checking cdr, I get a lot of php warnings/noitices like:

> PHP Notice:  Undefined index: modified in
>   /var/www/admin/libraries/BMO/Freepbx_conf.class.php on line 974

In details:

```
Checking cdr.. updated to 12.0.21
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: modified in /var/www/admin/libraries/BMO/Freepbx_conf.class.php on line 974
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: modified in /var/www/admin/libraries/BMO/Freepbx_conf.class.php on line 974
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: modified in /var/www/admin/libraries/BMO/Freepbx_conf.class.php on line 974
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: modified in /var/www/admin/libraries/BMO/Freepbx_conf.class.php on line 974
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: modified in /var/www/admin/libraries/BMO/Freepbx_conf.class.php on line 974
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: modified in /var/www/admin/libraries/BMO/Freepbx_conf.class.php on line 974
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: modified in /var/www/admin/libraries/BMO/Freepbx_conf.class.php on line 974
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: modified in /var/www/admin/libraries/BMO/Freepbx_conf.class.php on line 974
..OK
Setting freepbx settings form /etc/amportal.conf
freepbx setting [AMPDBHOST] DOES NOT EXIST, can't set to [localhost]
freepbx setting [AMPDBENGINE] DOES NOT EXIST, can't set to [mysql]
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: modified in /var/www/admin/libraries/BMO/Freepbx_conf.class.php on line 974
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: modified in /var/www/admin/libraries/BMO/Freepbx_conf.class.php on line 974
freepbx setting [AMPENGINE] set to [asterisk]
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: modified in /var/www/admin/libraries/BMO/Freepbx_conf.class.php on line 974
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: modified in /var/www/admin/libraries/BMO/Freepbx_conf.class.php on line 974
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: modified in /var/www/admin/libraries/BMO/Freepbx_conf.class.php on line 974
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: modified in /var/www/admin/libraries/BMO/Freepbx_conf.class.php on line 974
freepbx setting [AMPMGRUSER] set to [amiadmin]
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: modified in /var/www/admin/libraries/BMO/Freepbx_conf.class.php on line 974
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: modified in /var/www/admin/libraries/BMO/Freepbx_conf.class.php on line 974
freepbx setting [AMPMGRPASS] set to [dK839sqA41]
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: modified in /var/www/admin/libraries/BMO/Freepbx_conf.class.php on line 974
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: modified in /var/www/admin/libraries/BMO/Freepbx_conf.class.php on line 974
freepbx setting [AMPBIN] set to [/var/lib/asterisk/bin]
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: modified in /var/www/admin/libraries/BMO/Freepbx_conf.class.php on line 974
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: modified in /var/www/admin/libraries/BMO/Freepbx_conf.class.php on line 974
freepbx setting [AMPSBIN] set to [/usr/local/sbin]
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: modified in /var/www/admin/libraries/BMO/Freepbx_conf.class.php on line 974
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: modified in /var/www/admin/libraries/BMO/Freepbx_conf.class.php on line 974
freepbx setting [AMPWEBROOT] set to [/var/www]
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: modified in /var/www/admin/libraries/BMO/Freepbx_conf.class.php on line 974
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: modified in /var/www/admin/libraries/BMO/Freepbx_conf.class.php on line 974
freepbx setting [AMPCGIBIN] set to [/var/www/cgi-bin ]
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: modified in /var/www/admin/libraries/BMO/Freepbx_conf.class.php on line 974
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: modified in /var/www/admin/libraries/BMO/Freepbx_conf.class.php on line 974
freepbx setting [FOPWEBROOT] set to [/var/www/html/panel]
freepbx setting [FOPPASSWORD] DOES NOT EXIST, can't set to [passw0rd]
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: modified in /var/www/admin/libraries/BMO/Freepbx_conf.class.php on line 974
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: modified in /var/www/admin/libraries/BMO/Freepbx_conf.class.php on line 974
freepbx setting [AUTHTYPE] set to [database]
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: modified in /var/www/admin/libraries/BMO/Freepbx_conf.class.php on line 974
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: modified in /var/www/admin/libraries/BMO/Freepbx_conf.class.php on line 974
freepbx setting [AMPEXTENSIONS] set to [extensions]
freepbx setting [AMPDBUSER] DOES NOT EXIST, can't set to [asteriskuser]
freepbx setting [AMPDBPASS] DOES NOT EXIST, can't set to [xxwDaUN5njRL0EDMu]
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: modified in /var/www/admin/libraries/BMO/Freepbx_conf.class.php on line 974
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: modified in /var/www/admin/libraries/BMO/Freepbx_conf.class.php on line 974
freepbx setting [AMPWEBADDRESS] set to [192.168.1.1]
freepbx setting [AMPDBNAME] DOES NOT EXIST, can't set to [asterisk]
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: modified in /var/www/admin/libraries/BMO/Freepbx_conf.class.php on line 974
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: modified in /var/www/admin/libraries/BMO/Freepbx_conf.class.php on line 974
freepbx setting [ASTETCDIR] set to [/etc/asterisk]
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: modified in /var/www/admin/libraries/BMO/Freepbx_conf.class.php on line 974
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: modified in /var/www/admin/libraries/BMO/Freepbx_conf.class.php on line 974
freepbx setting [ASTMODDIR] set to [/usr/lib/asterisk/modules]
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: modified in /var/www/admin/libraries/BMO/Freepbx_conf.class.php on line 974
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: modified in /var/www/admin/libraries/BMO/Freepbx_conf.class.php on line 974
freepbx setting [ASTVARLIBDIR] set to [/var/lib/asterisk]
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: modified in /var/www/admin/libraries/BMO/Freepbx_conf.class.php on line 974
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: modified in /var/www/admin/libraries/BMO/Freepbx_conf.class.php on line 974
freepbx setting [ASTAGIDIR] set to [/var/lib/asterisk/agi-bin]
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: modified in /var/www/admin/libraries/BMO/Freepbx_conf.class.php on line 974
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: modified in /var/www/admin/libraries/BMO/Freepbx_conf.class.php on line 974
freepbx setting [ASTSPOOLDIR] set to [/var/spool/asterisk]
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: modified in /var/www/admin/libraries/BMO/Freepbx_conf.class.php on line 974
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: modified in /var/www/admin/libraries/BMO/Freepbx_conf.class.php on line 974
freepbx setting [ASTRUNDIR] set to [/var/run/asterisk]
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: modified in /var/www/admin/libraries/BMO/Freepbx_conf.class.php on line 974
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: modified in /var/www/admin/libraries/BMO/Freepbx_conf.class.php on line 974
freepbx setting [ASTLOGDIR] set to [/var/log/asterisk]
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: modified in /var/www/admin/libraries/BMO/Freepbx_conf.class.php on line 974
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: modified in /var/www/admin/libraries/BMO/Freepbx_conf.class.php on line 974
freepbx setting [FPBXDBUGFILE] set to [/var/log/asterisk/freepbx_debug]
Generating AMP configs..
Generating Configurations.conf, (if Asterisk is not running, you will get an error)
In case of error, start Asterisk and hit the red bar in the GUI to generate the Configurations.conf files
PHP Warning:  file_put_contents(/var/log/asterisk/freepbx.log): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/admin/libraries/utility.functions.php on line 112
PHP Warning:  file_put_contents(/var/log/asterisk/freepbx.log): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/admin/libraries/utility.functions.php on line 112
PHP Warning:  file_put_contents(/var/log/asterisk/freepbx.log): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/admin/libraries/utility.functions.php on line 112
PHP Warning:  file_put_contents(/var/log/asterisk/freepbx.log): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/admin/libraries/utility.functions.php on line 112
PHP Warning:  file_put_contents(/var/log/asterisk/freepbx.log): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/admin/libraries/utility.functions.php on line 112
Checking for PEAR Console::Getopt..OK
PHP Warning:  file_put_contents(/var/log/asterisk/freepbx.log): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/admin/libraries/utility.functions.php on line 112
Running module install.php and install.sql scripts
PHP Warning:  file_put_contents(/var/log/asterisk/freepbx.log): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/admin/libraries/utility.functions.php on line 112
Skipping extension and destination registry checks
PHP Warning:  file_put_contents(/var/log/asterisk/freepbx.log): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/admin/libraries/utility.functions.php on line 112
PHP Warning:  file_put_contents(/var/log/asterisk/freepbx.log): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/admin/libraries/utility.functions.php on line 112
PHP Warning:  file_put_contents(/var/log/asterisk/freepbx.log): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/admin/libraries/utility.functions.php on line 112
PHP Warning:  file_put_contents(/var/log/asterisk/freepbx.log): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/admin/libraries/utility.functions.php on line 112
PHP Warning:  file_put_contents(/var/log/asterisk/freepbx.log): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/admin/libraries/utility.functions.php on line 112
PHP Warning:  file_put_contents(/var/log/asterisk/freepbx.log): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/admin/libraries/utility.functions.php on line 112
PHP Warning:  file_put_contents(/var/log/asterisk/freepbx.log): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/admin/libraries/utility.functions.php on line 112
PHP Warning:  file_put_contents(/var/log/asterisk/freepbx.log): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/admin/libraries/utility.functions.php on line 112
PHP Warning:  file_put_contents(/var/log/asterisk/freepbx.log): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/admin/libraries/utility.functions.php on line 112
PHP Warning:  file_put_contents(/var/log/asterisk/freepbx.log): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/admin/libraries/utility.functions.php on line 112
PHP Warning:  file_put_contents(/var/log/asterisk/freepbx.log): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/admin/libraries/utility.functions.php on line 112
PHP Warning:  file_put_contents(/var/log/asterisk/freepbx.log): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/admin/libraries/utility.functions.php on line 112
PHP Warning:  file_put_contents(/var/log/asterisk/freepbx.log): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/admin/libraries/utility.functions.php on line 112
PHP Warning:  file_put_contents(/var/log/asterisk/freepbx.log): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/admin/libraries/utility.functions.php on line 112
PHP Warning:  file_put_contents(/var/log/asterisk/freepbx.log): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/admin/libraries/utility.functions.php on line 112
PHP Warning:  file_put_contents(/var/log/asterisk/freepbx.log): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/admin/libraries/utility.functions.php on line 112
PHP Warning:  file_put_contents(/var/log/asterisk/freepbx.log): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/admin/libraries/utility.functions.php on line 112
PHP Warning:  file_put_contents(/var/log/asterisk/freepbx.log): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/admin/libraries/utility.functions.php on line 112
PHP Warning:  file_put_contents(/var/log/asterisk/freepbx.log): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/admin/libraries/utility.functions.php on line 112
PHP Warning:  file_put_contents(/var/log/asterisk/freepbx.log): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/admin/libraries/utility.functions.php on line 112
PHP Warning:  file_put_contents(/var/log/asterisk/freepbx.log): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/admin/libraries/utility.functions.php on line 112
no crontab for asterisk
no crontab for asterisk
Please update your modules and reload Asterisk by visiting http://192.168.1.1/admin
PHP Warning:  file_put_contents(/var/log/asterisk/freepbx.log): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/admin/libraries/utility.functions.php on line 112
PHP Warning:  file_put_contents(/var/log/asterisk/freepbx.log): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/admin/libraries/utility.functions.php on line 112
PHP Warning:  file_put_contents(/var/log/asterisk/freepbx.log): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/admin/libraries/utility.functions.php on line 112
PHP Warning:  file_put_contents(/var/log/asterisk/freepbx.log): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/admin/libraries/utility.functions.php on line 112
PHP Warning:  file_put_contents(/var/log/asterisk/freepbx.log): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/admin/libraries/utility.functions.php on line 112
```

Also, the most important, I get this error

```
Untaring..Done
Module ucp successfully downloaded
Refreshing all UCP Assets, this could take a while...
PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare class UCP\UCP in /var/www/admin/modules/ucp/htdocs/includes/UCP.class.php on line 217
```

when running:

> amportal a ma installall

Comment: After running freepbx i get this error:
Error(s) have occured, the following is the retrieve_conf output:
exit: 1
found language dir fr for directory, not installed on system, skipping
[FATAL] SELECT custom_exten, description FROM custom_extensions  [nativecode=1146 ** Table 'asterisk.custom_extensions' doesn't exist]SQL - &lt;br /&gt; SELECT custom_exten, description FROM custom_extensions

Comment: if you have issues with install, use centos 6 and piaf.it fully automatic. imho mainissues here is nessages about db on install

Comment: Thanks, but i want to install it on Ubuntu.

Comment: No problem, you are welcome.  But you still have setup database correct way.

Comment: Solved, the problem was somewhere in freepbx scripts. I used version freepbx12.0.70.tgz, so i downloaded freepbx12.0.3.tgz and it solved my problem, also it automatically updated to version 12.0.71 ))

Comment: @John, would you consider adding an answer below? We encourage self-answers here. You can then click the tick mark to the left of it, to mark the question as resolved (we prefer this to marking the title as [solved]). Thanks!

Comment: Please don't add *solved* to your question title. Instead, mark your self-answer as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

**Solved**, the problem was somewhere in freepbx scripts. I used version freepbx12.0.70.tgz, so i downloaded freepbx12.0.3.tgz and it solved my problem, also it automatically updated to version 12.0.71.